# Issues with nested "ifelse()" referencing previous row via "shift()"

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to apply various business logic to my source dataset, using nested ifelse() and shift(), but my code is giving me results that I don't understand.   The problem statement is the following: I have a customer dataset containing "CustomerID", "Month", and "Status".

```
CustomerID  Month   Status
43210       1/1/18  A
43210       2/1/18  B
43210       3/1/18  A
43210       4/1/18  B
43210       5/1/18  C
43210       6/1/18  D
43210       7/1/18  B
6543        1/1/19  C
6543        2/1/19  D
6543        3/1/19  A
6543        4/1/19  B
6543        5/1/19  C
6543        6/1/19  A
```

I need to create a third column called "Journey_Status" by applying the following logic.

```r
#Initialize the 1st record of each Customer.
Example1$Journey_Status=ifelse(!duplicated(Example1[,c("CustomerID")]), Example1$Status, "")

Example1[ , Journey_Status := ifelse(duplicated(CustomerID),
   ifelse(shift(Journey_Status, 1, type="lag") == "A" &
          Status %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
          Status,
   ifelse(shift(Journey_Status, 1, type="lag") == "B" &
          Status %in% c("B", "C", "D"),
          Status,
   ifelse(shift(Journey_Status, 1, type="lag") == "C" &
          Status %in% c("C", "D"),
          Status,
   ifelse(shift(Journey_Status, 1, type="lag") == "D" &
          Status %in% c("D"),
          Status,
          shift(Journey_Status, 1, type="lag"))))),
Journey_Status)][]
```

I am expecting to see the following:

```
CustomerID  Month   Status  Journey_Status
43210       1/1/18  A       A
43210       2/1/18  B       B
43210       3/1/18  A       B
43210       4/1/18  B       B
43210       5/1/18  C       C
43210       6/1/18  D       D
43210       7/1/18  B       D
6543        1/1/19  C       C
6543        2/1/19  D       D
6543        3/1/19  A       D
6543        4/1/19  B       D
6543        5/1/19  C       D
6543        6/1/19  A       D
```

Instead I am getting the following:

```
CustomerID  Month   Status  Journey_Status
43210       1/1/18  A       A
43210       2/1/18  B       B
43210       3/1/18  A       
43210       4/1/18  B       
43210       5/1/18  C       
43210       6/1/18  D       
43210       7/1/18  B       
6543        1/1/19  C       C
6543        2/1/19  D       D
6543        3/1/19  A       
6543        4/1/19  B       
6543        5/1/19  C       
6543        6/1/19  A
```

I don't see the `shift()` being executed...   Your help much appreciated!!!   Thank you!!!

Comment: I suggest you convert A,B,C... to 1,2,3... and to a cumulative max by customer id.

Comment: I often discourage the use of base R's `ifelse`, as it does not always preserve class. If you're already using `data.table`, I suggest `data.table::fifelse`. Similarly, if you're in the tidyverse, use `dplyr::if_else`. Both provide better class-preservation and consistency (to varying degrees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current implementation:

1. Do your per-`CustomerID` grouping with the `by=` operator, do not try to do it manually with `duplicated`. This seems similar to how spreadsheets force us to think (since they generally do not facilitate operating by-group), where "if this line's id is different than the last line's id, do something different". Trust in `data.table`'s `by=` operator (or `dplyr::group_by` or several others).
2. You are not accounting for the new "shifted" element in `shift`, either by `fill=` or some other mechanism. This is introducing an `NA` in the column, see #3 code.
3. Unfortunately, your implementation is only valid at a point in time: even if we correct for the grouping and over use the `fifelse` fields (I tend to think that more than 2-3 nested is over-using), then we still see a problem:

   ```r
   dat[, lagstat := shift(Status, type = "lag"), by = .(CustomerID) ]
   dat[, Journey_Status :=
           fifelse(is.na(lagstat), Status,
                   fifelse(lagstat == "A" & Status %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Status,
                           fifelse(lagstat == "B" & Status %in% c("B", "C", "D"), Status,
                                   fifelse(lagstat == "C" & Status %in% c("C", "D"), Status,
                                           fifelse(lagstat == "D" & Status %in% c("D"), Status,
                                                   lagstat))))),
       by = .(CustomerID)]
   dat
   #     CustomerID  Month Status lagstat Journey_Status
   #  1:      43210 1/1/18      A    <NA>              A
   #  2:      43210 2/1/18      B       A              B
   #  3:      43210 3/1/18      A       B              B
   #  4:      43210 4/1/18      B       A              B
   #  5:      43210 5/1/18      C       B              C
   #  6:      43210 6/1/18      D       C              D
   #  7:      43210 7/1/18      B       D              D
   #  8:       6543 1/1/19      C    <NA>              C
   #  9:       6543 2/1/19      D       C              D
   # 10:       6543 3/1/19      A       D              D
   # 11:       6543 4/1/19      B       A              B  # fail
   # 12:       6543 5/1/19      C       B              C  # fail
   # 13:       6543 6/1/19      A       C              C  # fail
   ```

   While this looks better, let's look at where it fails: row 11. When it checks the value of `lagstat`, it looks at it at the time before this `fifelse` chain started, not immediately after the previous row's `fifelse` was processed. That is, it calculates all of the vectors within the `fifelse`s based on the same state of data. Even if you do `shift` within each `fifelse`, it's not going to see the value of the previous lagged value.

I think what you need is a cumulative function. I'm going to assume that there is clear ordinality to the data, where `max` will work. For the record, while I'd prefer to use `cummax`, `max(c("A", "B"))` works but `cummax(c("A", "B"))` does not. So we do it manually, using `Reduce(..., accumulate=TRUE)`.

Starting with fresh `dat` data.

```r
dat[, Journey_Status := Reduce(max, Status, accumulate = TRUE),
    by = .(CustomerID) ]
dat
#     CustomerID  Month Status Journey_Status
#  1:      43210 1/1/18      A              A
#  2:      43210 2/1/18      B              B
#  3:      43210 3/1/18      A              B
#  4:      43210 4/1/18      B              B
#  5:      43210 5/1/18      C              C
#  6:      43210 6/1/18      D              D
#  7:      43210 7/1/18      B              D
#  8:       6543 1/1/19      C              C
#  9:       6543 2/1/19      D              D
# 10:       6543 3/1/19      A              D
# 11:       6543 4/1/19      B              D
# 12:       6543 5/1/19      C              D
# 13:       6543 6/1/19      A              D
```

Even if `max` does not work, if you have a home-grown function that handles ordinality manually, then you can replace that for `max` and this should work.

Side note: DanY's suggestion that if your `Status` were truly integer or numeric, then this would be even simpler:

```r
datnum[, Journey_Status := cummax(Status), by = .(CustomerID) ]
datnum
#     CustomerID  Month Status Journey_Status
#  1:      43210 1/1/18      1              1
#  2:      43210 2/1/18      2              2
#  3:      43210 3/1/18      1              2
#  4:      43210 4/1/18      2              2
#  5:      43210 5/1/18      3              3
#  6:      43210 6/1/18      4              4
#  7:      43210 7/1/18      2              4
#  8:       6543 1/1/19      3              3
#  9:       6543 2/1/19      4              4
# 10:       6543 3/1/19      1              4
# 11:       6543 4/1/19      2              4
# 12:       6543 5/1/19      3              4
# 13:       6543 6/1/19      1              4
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- fread(text="
CustomerID  Month   Status
43210       1/1/18  A
43210       2/1/18  B
43210       3/1/18  A
43210       4/1/18  B
43210       5/1/18  C
43210       6/1/18  D
43210       7/1/18  B
6543        1/1/19  C
6543        2/1/19  D
6543        3/1/19  A
6543        4/1/19  B
6543        5/1/19  C
6543        6/1/19  A")

datnum <- fread(text="
CustomerID  Month   Status
43210       1/1/18  1
43210       2/1/18  2
43210       3/1/18  1
43210       4/1/18  2
43210       5/1/18  3
43210       6/1/18  4
43210       7/1/18  2
6543        1/1/19  3
6543        2/1/19  4
6543        3/1/19  1
6543        4/1/19  2
6543        5/1/19  3
6543        6/1/19  1")
```

Comment: hi, a suggestion to convert character to integer so as to use `cummax`: `status <- setNames(1L:4L, LETTERS[1L:4L]); DT[, names(status)[cummax(status[Status])], CustomerID]`

Comment: Many thanks to all and "r2evans" for putting the care and details in your responses.   Unfortunately, there is no clear ordinality to the data and using "max" is not an option.   Therefore, any advice on how I can create a home-grown function that handles ordinality manually?   Note the business rules may be complex, for example looking at time between status and only allowing certain number of journeys.   Again THANK YOU for your and everyone's help!!

Comment: Robert, I don't know what to say. Your example has the ordering based solely on itself, not on business rules that require other fields.

Comment: Perhaps it's a different/new question, but ... how do you intend to order things? If you say it is complicated and based on business rules, then I think it's perhaps unrelated to this question but still something to work through. Most sorting routines (even based on "business rules" can be broken down to a combination of `order` values, possibly with `xtfrm`. The only time it isn't possible with those two functions (or `dplyr::arrange`) is when there are subjective determinations.

Comment: I might have over simplify the question.   The original question is to track customer behavior over time--dataset is sorted by customerID & month/date.   There're +500 different activities that's grouped into categories (A=Web Enrollment Activities, B=Provided Profile Activities, C=Download Online Discount, and etc.)   A customer may Web Enrolled (A) & provide their profile info(B), and never downloaded the discount.   A week later customer Web enrolled again (A) & provided profile (B) & downloaded the discount (C).   Dataset needs to be transform into A B B B C.   Many thanks for the help!!

Comment: How can I add a "home-grown function that handles ordinality manually" to the "reduce" function?

Comment: You first have to state those requirements, in a way that is mathematically/logically unambiguous (sometimes finding the corner-cases or holes in this logic takes practice, depends on the attempted logic).